# two different comboxBoxes show the same value as one of them changes

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I am programming with `c#` in visual studio,I have two `combobox` named    1) `senderReferringComboBox`    and  2)`recieverReferringComboBox`
I am populating these two `comboBox` like this

```
   DataSet myDataSet = new DataSet();
   string sql = " Select dbo.Position.ID, dbo.Position.usr_Id as UserId, dbo.Position.Title + ' (' + dbo._User.LastName + ' ' + dbo._User.FirstName + ')' AS UserPosition" +
                " FROM  dbo._User INNER JOIN " +
                " dbo.Position ON dbo._User.ID = dbo.Position.usr_Id " +
                " WHERE (dbo._User.IsActive = 1) and dbo._User.Id !=" + UIHelper.CurrentUser.Id +
                " ORDER BY dbo.Position.Title";

   DataTable table = client.GetDataTable(null, sql, null);
   myDataSet.Tables.Add(table);

   DataView dvw1 = myDataSet.Tables[0].DefaultView;
   DataView dvw2 = myDataSet.Tables[0].DefaultView;

   senderReferringComboBox.DataSource = dvw1;
   senderReferringComboBox.DisplayMember = "UserPosition";
   senderReferringComboBox.ValueMember = "UserId";
   senderReferringComboBox.SelectedIndex = -1;

   recieverReferringComboBox.DataSource = dvw2;
   recieverReferringComboBox.DisplayMember = "UserPosition";
   recieverReferringComboBox.ValueMember = "UserId";
   recieverReferringComboBox.SelectedIndex = -1;
```

when I change a value in `senderReferringCombox` the same value  will be set on `recieverReferringComboBox`. I have set two different views ? why does it happen? how can I prevent it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create new views for each `ComboBox DataSource` because if you use `DefaultView` you get the same view both times.

Change your code like this to make it work:

```
DataView dvw1 = new DataView(myDataSet.Tables[0]);
DataView dvw2 = new DataView(myDataSet.Tables[0]);
```